# Custom underlines in CSS for text with line breaks

Tags: css, underline

Is there any way to underline a large hunk of text in a custom way with CSS/JS? I don't know what the text is gonna be and it can have line breaks in it, so I can't go the regular way of using a border-bottom.

---

*Sorry, if the question wasn't clear. The key word is 'custom'. Like different-colored dashed line or some fancy stars, or whatever. We can do this with background or border-bottom properties, but only for a single line of text. If there is a line break it will only be applied to the bottom. That's what I meant.*

Comment: `text-decoration: underline;`?

Comment: are you able to apply some classes over that text if yes than write a class including above given property and apply to that element that contain the text.

Answer (score 3):

The `text-decoration` attribute is what you're looking for. If you have the class `underlined` assigned to the enclosing element whose text you want to underline, your CSS would look like this:

```
.underlined {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Comment: +1, but consider renaming your class based on content not the specific style you want to apply. Here is a [good article](http://css-tricks.com/13423-semantic-class-names/) about semantic class names.

Comment: Of course, but we have no idea what the semantics are in this case. I erred on the side of being non-semantic rather than make something up that could be confusing.

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified I was addressing Daniel. :-)